# In CSS, how can I make a vertically centered line which takes up the remaining horizontal space after a block element?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am implementing a design which contains elements which are semantically headers (h3, h4, etc.), are full-width block elements, and are followed by a vertically centered horizontal line which extends the full width of the header a la:

[image: headers]

I know I could take care of this by wrapping each header in a `<div>` and inserting another block-level element after it but would prefer not to pollute my HTML like that.  My first inclination was to use a `::after` element on the headers, like so:

```
.line-header::after {
    content:'\00a0';
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

However, this requires making the `::after` element fixed-width, which obviously doesn't work with different-width headers: http://jsfiddle.net/nbSTf/

Any ideas on how to get a variable-width line which will fill the space to the right of the header, without inserting extra elements into the HTML?

**EDIT:** Tyriar's answer below (suggesting drawing the line full-width behind the header and setting the background-color to erase the line behind the text) reminded me that this is taking place in front of a repeating background image - so no background tricks are possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your CSS:

**EDIT**:

```
body { background: red; overflow-x: hidden }

.line-header {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 100;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.line-header::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'\00a0';
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I only tested this in Chrome. [Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvanscoy/s8rHH/).

Comment: I was impressed with your method and didn't really know what was going on. I had play with it and apparently it can break pretty easily without a wrapper around `.line-header` http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/uJ5ww/ still, nice solution :)

Comment: This is an interesting solution - however, even in Tyriar's fiddle where the wrapper div constrains the "width: 100%" to a reasonable amount, if you scroll to the right of the Result pane, the horizontal lines are still the same width, with the one for the longer header pushed farther to the right - the same problem I had but in reverse. :)  I need them to line up at the RH edge of the containing element.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Eric P my fiddle showed a counter example, not a fix. Also overflow-x will probably not be sufficient. That will only work if the content wasn't centered in the page and padding on the right wasn't desired.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying.  You would just need overflow-x:hidden on whatever contains the headers. As long as overflow-x:hidden is acceptable for that container, then I don't see why that's not a valid solution.  Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvanscoy/xkQ7C/) where the headers are wrapped by a div container with a set width which is centered in the browser.

Comment: @JacobVanScoy that works, change your answer to use #container instead of body.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method you could do it with, unfortunately it relies on an attribute (not necessarily `title`), this could easily be set programmatically with JavaScript though.

It uses `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, `:after` is used to draw the line the full width and `:before` is used to draw white background behind the text of the size of the text. The pseudo-elements need their `z-index` set correctly to layer in the correct order.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uacbB/)

[image: Screenshot of example]

HTML

```
<h3 class="line-header" title="Longer Header Looks Good">Longer Header Looks Good</h3>
<h3 class="line-header" title="Short Doesn't">Short Doesn't</h3>
```

CSS

```
.line-header {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position:relative;
}
.line-header:before {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    content: attr(title);
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    z-index:-1;
    padding-right:.5em;
}
.line-header::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    display: block;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:50%;
    background-color:#555;
    height:1px;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyriar - I was initially looking at something much like this, but unfortunately the background behind the headers is a repeating image which nixes background tricks.  I will edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about doing it in reverse? Draw the lines (in any way you like) then use `:after` to insert the headers, no additional HTML, but some extra CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header1"></div>
<div id="header2"></div>
```

To Draw the Line, simply `border-top-style:solid;`.
To Write the headers, `:after`.

**CSS**

```
div
{
    position:relative;
    border-top-style:solid;
    margin-top:20px; /* just for spacing */
}
div:after
{
    display:block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:0px;
}
#header1:after
{
    content:"Hello;"
}
#header2:after
{
    content:"Hello Again";
}
```

You'll get something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/BKPnQ/)**.

For more customization, you can enlarge the font, change the colors, add padding (for more white space), just change `top` the way it suits you.